# spring application not picking up hbase-site.xml from cluster

Tags: hadoop, spring-boot, hbase

Can someone help me on how to point hbase-site.xml which i have on cluster to the spring boot rest-api developed in java.

note:

1. when I deploy the rest api jar file to the node where we have zookeeper, my rest api is working fine and able to fetch data from hbase.
2. when I deploy the rest api jar file to other node (edge node) where zookeeper is not there, restAPI looks for zookeeper @local host only. Although I have hbase.zookeeper.quorum and clientport updated correctly in hbase-site.xml
3. Rest api is working, if I hard code zookeeper quorum and client port and deploy it in edge node

Issue:

1. Need a solution on how to pass hbase-site.xml config file externally to restAPI to look for avoiding hard coding of zookeeper quorum and portnumber.
2. Cannot copy hbase-site.xml to one location and bind it as to avoid changes in code and again in prod if one zookeeper node goes down another zookeeper instance will be created but with different hostname.

Below is the command I am using to keep restAPI up.
nohup java -jar hbaseRestAPI.jar

Is there any plugin changes I can do in pom.xml so that HBaseConfiguration.create will create conf file taken from the directory which is pointed in pom.xml?

Thanks,

Sandeep.

Comment: Is hbase-site.xml packaged inside your jar? I usually put it under 'resources' and it works like a charm on machines outside the cluster.

Comment: No.. I am trying to find my jar to pick the hbase-site.xml from cluster. the reason for this is if zookeeper node goes down then another node with zookeeper will be created by auto repair function of cloudera manager. In this case zookeeper hostname would be different so if my jar is able to pick up hbase-site.xml from cluster, I no need to do any changes i.e. copying the latest hbase-site.xml and building jar and deploying it back..